# Reason for the signature of Crypto++ PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC class?

Tags: c++, interface, crypto++

In the Crypto++ manual for [PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k_c_s5___p_b_k_d_f2___h_m_a_c.html) there are two signatures of DeriveKey.

First:

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen, const byte *secret, size_t secretLen, const NameValuePairs &params=g_nullNameValuePairs) const
```

Second:

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen, byte purpose, const byte *secret, size_t secretLen, const byte *salt, size_t saltLen, unsigned int iterations, double timeInSeconds=0) const
```

I would like to understand the purpose of the last parameter in the first signature. 
`NameValuePairs &params=g_nullNameValuePairs`.

Unfortunately in the documentation I did not find an usage example.
Generally, my aim is to replace the calls of the second function with nullptr salts to first  but at the same time I need to send  `unsigned int iterations, double timeInSecond`.

Comment: Last parameter in the first signature is a default parameter which means you don't need to provide it when calling a function and it will still take value of `g_nullNameValuePairs` which is explained [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/cryptlib_8h.html#aa9048ef24353685fd0dcc4180c6884c2).

Comment: We added the missing documentation to the Crypto++ wiki. See [PKCS12_PBKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS12_PBKDF), [PKCS5_PBKDF1](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS5_PBKDF1), and [PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC). Sorry about the missing docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your fist case, this signature is part of the [`KeyDerivationFunction`](https://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_key_derivation_function.html) interface. Nearly all KDF's derive from it. The only KDF that does not derive from it is `P1363_KDF2`, which is used as a mask generation function in padding schemes.

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen,
                   const byte *secret, size_t secretLen,
                   const NameValuePairs &params=g_nullNameValuePairs) const
```

This signature was selected because the essence of a KDF is to takes a seed or secret, and output derived keying material. Other parameters, like usage, iteration count or memory cost, are value added parameters.

The `NameValuePairs` allow passing of arbitrary parameters. It is needed because KDF parameters vary wildly. For example, early PBKDF often use a single "usage" octet and "iteration count" in its derivation; while Scrypt uses "memory hardness" or "cost" in its derivation. With `NameValuePairs` those varying parameters can be passed through a consistent interface.

The `KeyDerivationFunction` class also provides a few helpers, like `MinDerivedKeyLength`, `MaxDerivedKeyLength`, `GetValidDerivedLength` and `IsValidDerivedLength`. `GetValidDerivedLength` is a virtual function, and all derived classes must implement it.

For your second case, this signature is more specialized. It is retained because it was present in the early days of Crypto++. It handles several old KDFs like `P1363_KDF2`, `PKCS12_PBKDF`, `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC`, but fails to handle newer KDFs, like Argon, HKDF and Scrypt.

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen,
                   byte purpose,
                   const byte *secret, size_t secretLen,
                   const byte *salt, size_t saltLen,
                   unsigned int iterations, double timeInSeconds=0) const
```

If we wanted to handle modern KDFs, then the newer signature with more parameters would look something like:

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen,
                   byte purpose,
                   const byte *secret, size_t secretLen,
                   const byte *salt, size_t saltLen,
                   const byte *pepper, size_t pepperLen,  // additional data
                   const byte *info, size_t infoLen,      // additional data
                   word32 iterations,
                   word32 version,           // Argon2
                   word32 type,              // Argon2
                   word32 rho,               // Argon2
                   word64 memsize,           // Argon2
                   word64 cost,              // Scrypt
                   word64 blockSize,         // Scrypt
                   word64 parallelization    // Scrypt
                   double timeInSeconds=0 ) const
```

As you can see, this is getting out of hand quickly.

So what we now do is, use the `KeyDerivationFunction` interface and pass parameters through `NameValuePairs`:

```
std::string pass("password"), salt("NaCl");
word64 cost=1024, blockSize=8, parallelization=16;

AlgorithmParameters params = MakeParameters("Cost", cost)
    ("BlockSize", blockSize)("Parallelization", parallelization)
    ("Salt", ConstByteArrayParameter((const byte*)&salt[0], salt.size()));

SecByteBlock derived(64);
scrypt.DeriveKey(derived, derived.size(), ConstBytePtr(pass), BytePtrSize(pass), params);
```

However, nothing forbids a derived class like HKDF or Scrypt from providing a overloaded `DeriveKey` that only accepts its exact parameters, and that is what HKDF, Scrypt and other KDFs do.

Here is Scrypt's overload. These are the exact parameters used in `DeriveKey`:

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen,
                   const byte *secret, size_t secretLen,
                   const byte *salt, size_t saltLen, 
                   word64 cost=2, word64 blockSize=8,
                   word64 parallelization=1) const
```

And here is HKDF's overloaded `DeriveKey`. These are the exact parameters used in its derivation function:

```
size_t  DeriveKey (byte *derived, size_t derivedLen, 
                   const byte *secret, size_t secretLen,
                   const byte *salt, size_t saltLen,
                   const byte *info, size_t infoLen) const
```

---

Note the new `KeyDerivationFunction` interface with the `NameValuePair` was added at Crypto++ 6.2 under Issue 610:

- [Issue 610](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/610)

Here is some more reading from the Crypto++ wiki:

- [KeyDerivationFunction](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/KeyDerivationFunction)
- [NameValuePairs](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/NameValuePairs)
- [P1363_KDF2](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/P1363_KDF2)
- [PKCS12_PBKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS12_PBKDF)
- [PKCS5_PBKDF1](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS5_PBKDF1)
- [PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC)
- [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HKDF), [Scrypt](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Scrypt)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It helped me a lot :)